# Trying to extract data from a JSON

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I'm using tabula-py to extract some data in JSON format and it is returning:
`[{'extraction_method': 'stream', 'top': 580.635, 'left': 699.435, 'width': 49.5, 'height': 15.8399658203125, 'right': 748.935, 'bottom': 596.475, 'data': [[{'top': 586.55, 'left': 701.77, 'width': 33.569969177246094, 'height': 4.809999942779541, 'text': '1,227.57'}]]}]`

I'm trying to get the `data.text` attribute which I'm struggling to get to. I've tried variations of:
`consignment_balance[0]['data']`

Looking for a hand as I'm not familiar with Python syntax.

Comment: `consignment_balance[0]['data'][0][0]['text']`.  You'll need to consider when those lists might have more than one item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the value from the `JSON` bit tricky here.

```
consignment_balance[0]['data'][0][0]['text']
# '1,227.57'
```

It has a nested list and dictionary so you need to access it accordingly.